# JSQMessageViewController - outgoing text alignment

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I would like to set the sender's reply without outgoing avatar, so i setup the outgoing avatar image to nil like below:

> self.outgoingAvatarImage = [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory
>                                   avatarImageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]
>                                               diameter:kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault];

but it make the outgoing text alignment miss align like the following screen.

[outgoing text alignment sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE6xu.png)
, how can i set the alignment to the red line like the screen shot given?

[attachment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfFko.png)

Answer (score 0):

As i'm understanding your question, you should just add following line in `viewDidAppear` -

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
```

or other required frame ( for width so that you can manage some space )

Comment: thanks for the question and it didn't work for me. please allow me to clarify the question, my application will not showing the outgoing avatar, but the outgoing text separate to the next line at green line instead of red line as per attached (see attachment 2). how do I make the outgoing text align on the red line?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the trailing constraints was set to -32, set the constraints to 0 will solve the problem.

[Bubble Container trailing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smn3C.png)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!